# User Expiring Before Creation Date

Tags: linux, ubuntu, accounts, expired

### [21:00] Server Message:

### Your account has expired;  please contact your system administrator.

Why do accounts created with useradd expire at 21:00 and not at the exact time of their creation?

When I create a user using useradd in linux, that user will not expire exactly the next day at the time of creation. it will always expire at 21:00 no matter what time it was created.

I would like to know if it would be possible to change this time from 21:00 to the user creation time or to a specific time.

I'm using the command...

```
useradd -M -N -s /bin/false $user -e $validity -c $validity
```

Comment: do we guess the value of `$validity`? though, the manual does state that `The date is specified in the format YYYY-MM-DD` - what timezone are you in? perhaps that's a factor